# Is Stack Overflow open source?

Tags: discussion

In an effort to learn about the system, I was trying to find out if I can get to see the source code to the application. If it's not open source that is okay, I will just try to understand it.

Comment: No.  Though a fun question might be "does the source-code for Stack Overflow incorporate any code from any answers present on Stack Overflow"?  Because if it does, and if those answers were authored prior to February 2016, there are...[implications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 101):

Stack Overflow itself is not open source, but there are a number of [open source Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones) to choose from.

There are also a number of components of Stack Overflow that have been made openly available by the dev team. You can read about them on the blog: [Stack Exchange Open Source Projects](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchange-open-source-projects/)

Comment: That blog post is very out of date - it still links to Google Code which shut down months ago.

Answer (score 27):

[Will Stack Overflow's engine be open sourced?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35/will-stack-overflows-engine-be-open-sourced) No.

You may be interested in studying the source code to [Discourse](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/222187/148099), which is an independent project by one of the founders of Stack Overflow, and is loosely based on similar ideas.

Comment: Although... Discourse is a new Forum engine while Stack Overflow is not, and there is no "score" on Discourse (or I've missed it), etc... so it's very loose indeed.

Comment: Sure, Discourse (Open Source, Ruby + JavaScript) and SO (Proprietary, ASP.NET MVC + JavaScript) are roughly as *loosely based on similar ideas* as the United States and China.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: ... they're both democratic People's Republics? :P

Comment: @Nathan, more like both a bunch of people on the same soil :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi they are (famously?) developed by people *not* on the same soil.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi it's good to know that SO and Discourse chose JavaScript as their front-end engine.  I'd be worried if they didn't.

Comment: Also, in my experience, Discourse makes me want to throw my computer out the window and go live in a cave.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo CoffeeScript 1.0.0 was released in 2010, so even in 2013 when Discourse was started there were alternatives.