# Can Stack Overflow release the source code for the image uploader?

Tags: feature-request, code

Is it possible to open-source the Imgur image uploader you have made for profile pictures etc.?

I know this can be accomplished but it would make life just that little bit easier for so many devs. Let me know what you all think!

If the answer is no, I would be interested to hear Stack Overflow's policy on releasing source code.

This is definitely not a duplicate of [Is Stack Overflow open source?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313483/is-stack-overflow-open-source) This is a very specific question and is also a request not a general question.

Comment: Why do you specifically want SE's image upload? There's plenty of libraries out there...

Comment: @Cerbrus This is a much more specific question. Also, would you be able to list some examples of libraries?

Comment: So you ask us to go shopping for you?

Comment: There's nothing magic about their image uploader. It simply uses the [Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com). The only thing unique about it is they have their own private sub-domain from Imgur, but you don't *need* that.

Comment: @rene I have looked and have not been able to find anything similar. Yes, I know there is the API but I meant something specifically like this. I was simply asking if there was anything that you found that I missed.

Comment: Here is everything that is opensourced by [Stack Exchange](https://github.com/StackExchange) and the rest of the essential info is provided by Cody.

Comment: They are using a library called [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), with almost no customizations. Dropzone allows drag-and-drop for files, image preview, and simple file upload.

Comment: @Kobi Thanks so much if you add this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @Booligoosh - No problem. I can't add an answer because the question is closed. Either way, it is the first Google result on Cerbrus's answer ("*resources out there*").

Comment: @Kobi yes, although I didn't previously know this is what SO uses

Answer (score 7):

SO isn't open-source. ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313483/is-stack-overflow-open-source))
It doesn't seem likely that that's going to change.

A image upload is something that's been invented, re-invented, reverse engineered, sent into space, dug up where X marked the spot on a deserted island, and copied a bazillion times before.

There are a lot of [resources out there](https://www.google.nl/search?q=image%20upload%20library) that can help you implement it.

As [@Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356426/can-stack-overflow-release-the-source-code-for-the-image-uploader/356427#comment513305_356426), SE uses the [Imgur API](https://apidocs.imgur.com/).

Comment: *sent into space* ... citation needed ... I may hope it was a PHP implementation ...

Comment: @rene: A PHP implementation would've burnt up during launch.

Comment: ...and taken the pad with it.